# How to ensure each SQS queue can have varying values for its lambda concurrency limit?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

each SQS queue represents a customer's "job". So setting a lambda concurrency limit to 5 doesnt make sense since there will be multiple customers creating many SQS queues or "jobs" to be processed by at most 5 lambda functions at a time.

however some customers who pay more money will desire to increase this, to say 20 lambda functions. how do I gaurantee each SQS queue's maximum lambda concurrency limit programmatically?

the idea is that while a lambda function is being triggered from an SQS queue event source. How do I make sure that at most only 5 lambda functions will be running at full capacity for one group of users and 20 for another group? so while the queue is filling up, the maximum number of concurrent messages being processed should be 5.

How do I ensure this programmatically through boto3?

> ```
>  import boto3
>  lada = boto3.client('lambda')
>  response=lada.create_event_source_mapping(
>                 EventSourceArn='jobSpecificQueueArn',
>                 FunctionName='myLambdaFunction',
>                 Enabled=True,
>                 BatchSize=1
>  )
> ```

Furthermore, how do I set a unique lambda concurrency limit *per* queue?

solution attempt: the only idea I have is creating several different lambda concurrency limit by cloning the same lambda function. Then if a customer wants to impose a limit of "14 lambda concurrency" on a given queue, I would just `create_event_sourcing()` with a `lambda-function-hard-limit-at-14`. If the user wants to scale down, I would `update_event_sourcing()` with a `lambda-function-hard-limit-at-3`.

down side is I will create duplicate lambda functions manually...roughly 20 times.

Comment: Side-question: Why do you wish to limit the concurrency of the queues? Is there something that might go wrong if too many functions run at the same time? Your cost for Lambda will not change based on concurrency.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Lambda Concurrency Limits and SQS Triggers Don’t Mix Well (Sometimes)](https://medium.com/@zaccharles/lambda-concurrency-limits-and-sqs-triggers-dont-mix-well-sometimes-eb23d90122e0)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes we must avoid sending too many HTTP requests. Each lambda function relies on HTTP requests to an external site which we dont want to overload.

Comment: hmmm...looks like it might be faster if I just setup long polling programmatically without relying on SQS triggers....